# How to format a tls record to be sent with winsock for https?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2, tls1.2, starttls

I have written a basic winsock client and am trying to implement tls for https later on. I have written a function which puts together the plaintext to be sent by winsock's

`int send(  SOCKET s,const char *buf,int len, int flags)`
as the `const char*` or `BYTE*` array.

```
BYTE * ComputeTLSRecordPlainText(BYTE * phandshakerequest, _in_ const int handshakesize, _out_ int * pTLSrecordsize, _in_ BYTE controltype, _in_ BYTE * protocolversion)
{
  *pTLSrecordsize = handshakesize + 5;
   BYTE * TLSPlainText = new BYTE[*pTLSrecordsize];
   TLSPlainText[0] = controltype; 
   TLSPlainText[1] = protocolversion[1]; //Major.
   TLSPlainText[2] = protocolversion[0]; //Minor.
   TLSPlainText[3] = handshakesize;
   TLSPlainText[4] = 0x0; // Refactor for messages greater than 255 bytes.
   for (int j = 5; j < *pTLSrecordsize; j++)
   {
      TLSPlainText[j] = phandshakerequest[j - 5];
   }
   return TLSPlainText;
}
```

The for loop appends the handshake message which itself has a hellomessage appended to it. For brevity I haven't included those here.

The only valid TLS response I have gotten was from google.com server which responds with a proper fatal alert with decimal code 70 : protocol_version.

Other sites either `recv()` doesn't return, or it does with error 10054. Or with http headers and bad request. I have initialized the connection with port 443?

So my question is this

**1)** Am I formatting the record correctly as far as Network byte order and endianess?

**2)** What is going on with difference in server responses? Could it be something with the TCP layer? Normal every day https is http over TLS over TCP correct?

Comment: Is there a requirement that you need to implement TLS on your own? Why not use an existing library which can handle it for you?

Comment: Just to be clear: you know you don't need to implement your own TLS? There's e.g. Windows's own schannel implementation you can use or OpenSSL or many others. Not that we'll stop you if you're doing it for education / fun, but if you're planning on using this for production you'll do better with someone else's.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I take interest in elliptical fields from mathematics and part of the purpose here is to implement the encryption protocols, provided I get to that point, this I think would provide the necessary flexibility.

Comment: Also I have a strange appetite for encodings I guess, audio, video, 3d obj.

Comment: I have sense solved some of this issue, I believe. I got caught up into how to shape the general architecture of it all. All the different handshake, encoding formats. But if interested can find my github under same user name with Transport layer interface dll which further implements this and solves this issues.